# Ошибка подключения к бд, при создании корзины

Tags: php, mysqli

Всем добрый день)) Практикуюсь на php, пишу корзину, но на 1 этапе добавления товара в бд, уже ошибки. Судя по всему нету соединения с бд, но как это пофиксить не могу понять) Большое спасибо!)

В этом файле config  я устанавливаю соединение с бд:

```
<?php

define (DB_HOST, 'localhost');
define(DB_LOGIN, 'root');
define(DB_PASSWORD, "");
define(DB_NAME, 'eshop');
define(ORDERS_LOG, 'orders.log');

$basket = array();
$count = 0;

$link = mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_LOGIN, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ('Unable to connect to mysql server: ' . mysqli_error());
```

В этом файле создана функция, которая добавляет товар:

```
<?php

require "config.inc.php";

function addItemToCatalog ($title, $author, $pubyear, $price) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO catalog (title, author, pubyear, price) VALUES ('$title', '$author', '$pubyear', '$price');";

    $stmt = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

    if (!$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $sql))
        return false;
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssii", $title, $author, $pubyear, $price);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    return true;
}
```

Здесь я вызываю функцию:

```
 <?php
    // подключение библиотек
    require "secure/session.inc.php";
    require "../inc/lib.inc.php";
    require "../inc/config.inc.php";

if(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST'){
    $title = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'title');
    $author = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'author');
    $pubyear = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'pubyear');
    $price = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'price');
}

addItemToCatalog ($title, $author, $pubyear, $price);
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\home\site.ru\www\eshop\inc\lib.inc.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\home\site.ru\www\eshop\inc\lib.inc.php on line 11
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: коротко - в нутри функции `addItemToCatalog` php понятия не имеет о переменной `$link`, решение в лоб - добавить строчку `global $link;` в начале функции